# can null or empty string can cause printing gibberish in log file?

Tags: android, c, eclipse, string

I have this line of code

```
char str[100];

..

   sBuffer.buffer = str;
   sBuffer.nBufferSize = sizeof(str);

   snprintf_safe(sBuffer,"%s %s", str, unit_str);
   navigate_bar_set_dist_str(str);


    logger_log(LOGGER_DEBUG, "sending time update to NavResultPopUp time = %s  maxNumToUpdateNavResultTime = %s", str, maxNumToUpdateNavResultTime);
```

but in the log file I see

`[14:48:12.707 Debug] sending time update to NavResultPopUp time = 14 ◊ì◊ß'[14:48:12.707 Debug] saving current configuration to file: session   [config.c:518 (config_save)]`

1) `str` is printed as gibberish

2) a line of the next logging in overriding the first log line before it's completed.

What values of `str` and `maxNumToUpdateNavResultTime` are dengearus to use here and could have caused this or other problems? (empty string, null.. ) ?

Comment: So you're using `sprintf_safe()`, whatever that is, to format a string `str` onto itself (`sBuffer.buffer` points to `str`)?

Comment: How can str & unit_str escaped be the same size as str?

Comment: What does `navigate_bar_set_dist_str` do?  Does it write to the argument?

Comment: @JohnBode it just prints it to the UI